# Running OpenJDK 11 Project in STS IDE

Tags: java, spring-boot, jlink, openjdk-11

I've been trying to migrate our projects from JDK 8 to OpenJDK 11. I also updated our Spring Boot version from 1.5.22 to 2.2.7. I was able to resolve the issues encountered during the migration. My only problem now is how can I run my application?

This is the sample structure of my project:

[image]

Since there's no JRE included in the OpenJDK 11 folder, I tried creating a module-info.java file which will then be used for generating the JRE. Instead of using the command line to check the dependencies of my project, I just use my IDE to generate it, (I'm using STS 4.6.2). I `right-clicked on my project -> Configure -> Create module-info.java`.

When I checked on the file, I was able to see that it also requires the dependency projects.

[image]

After that, I then tried cleaning and building the project and so no errors were found. But when I tried to start my service in the boot dashboard, it throws this error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module Rock.project.ServiceRunner not found
```

The ServiceRunner includes my main method.
After that, I also tried checking my ***Run Configurations*** and included this on the ***Arguments*** tab.

```
--module-path jlinkModule -m Rock.project.ServiceRunner
```

But I still get the same error. Any other suggestions on how I can run my springboot application? Thank you in advance!

Comment: *"Since there's no JRE included in the OpenJDK 11 folder"* Use the JDK folder. You don't need a dedicated JRE folder. Forget about generating a JRE, that's only to be used if you need to create an installation image that shouldn't rely on Java being installed separately.

Comment: @Andreas So I don't really need the module-info.java file? I've read some articles that I need to create a jre using jlink for the project to be able to run.

Comment: You only need that if you install the code on a computer where you don't want to install a full JDK.

Comment: @Andreas Oh, okay... So it should run if I just change the build properties and point it to my jdk.I'll try that. Thank you!